# Как избавиться от мигания WebView

Tags: android, webview

В приложении Android используется компонент WebView.

Для него указан фон таким образом:

```
mWeb.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fon_napominanie);
```

Далее в WebView грузятся html-странички, которые генерируются в коде. У страничек есть свой фон. Он задан таким образом:

```
tmp = tmp+ "<div style=\"text-align: center\"><img src=\"data:image/jpeg;base64,"+parser2.getText()+"\" alt width=\""+width+"\" height=\""+height+"\"></div>";
```

При смене страниц происходит мигание фона. Как от этого мигания избавится?

Comment: можете попробовать прятать вебвью на время, пока загружается страница. А фон выставить ку родительского элемента